# Extracting street address number from string (XSLT Map)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, mapping, biztalk

I have in my source schema an element with a string of a full address. In my destination schema I have to split this address field into two seperate fields containing the street and the street number.

I'm new to XSLT mapping and would like some input as to best go about this. I thought about writing a C# script to somehow extract the street number, as the format of the address is quite uniform.

Are there any of the default functoids that are able to handle this scenario? I would assume it is something that happens very often.

As an example, my destination schema expects this:

```
<Street>Via Alessandro Volta</Street>
<StreetNumber>142</StreetNumber>
```

My source schema has the address like this:

```
<ns0:Street>Heinrich-Eckstein-Str. 1</ns0:Street>
```

Comment: Would you like to get the following result: <Street>Heinrich-Eckstein-Str.</Street><StreetNumber>1</StreetNumber> from your source? I mean everthing except № of a building puts into <Street> and only a number go to <StreetNumber>. Do you want do it with XSL transform?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Could you attach entire source file or more filled file which contains other tags?

Comment: Can you post sample of xml file?  If you have a very large xml file and only need to extract a small number of items then I would recommend using XDocument instead of de-serializing the entire xml file.

Comment: *Very Important*  Is it the case that all you need to do is extract just the numbers from Street?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. I managed to fix it by extracting the last element of the input string and use as the street number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it with a simple C# code, using in your map "Scripting Functoid"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: You have to add 2 functoids, the source should be ns0:Street in both and the C# code must be different.